# Minimum manipulations to type the string

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

You have given a string called T, and you have to type it in the minimum manipulations.
There are 3 manipulations:

- **Insert** one character to the end of the string (we called S)
- **Copy** a substring in string S, the copied string will be stored in a clipboard
  and if you copy another substring, this substring will be delete of the clipboard
- **Paste** the copied-substring to the end of S

**Example 1:**
T=abcabab
We can use 6 manipulations:

1. Insert 'a' (S="a")
2. Insert 'b' (S="ab")
3. Insert 'c' (S="abc")
4. Copy "ab" into clipboard (S="abc"; clipboard: "ab")
5. Paste "ab" (S="abcab")
6. Paste "ab" (S="abcabab")

**Example 2:**
T =  aaaaaaaaaaa
We can use 7 manipulations:

1. Insert 'a' (S="a")
2. Insert 'a' (S="aa")
3. Insert 'a' (S="aaa")
4. Copy "aaa" into clipboard (S="aaa"; clipboard: "aaa")
5. Paste "aaa" (S="aaaaaa")
6. Copy "aaaaa" into clipboard (S="aaaaaa"; clipboard: "aaaaa")
7. Paste "aaaaa" (S="aaaaaaaaaaa")

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: My questions is in the header, you have given a string called T, a string S ="", and you have to change S to T in the minimum manipulations.

Comment: That's a problem statement. What is your question regarding this problem?

Comment: It's finding the minimum manipulations to type the string like the examples

Comment: "and you have to type it in.." seems like a keyboard xtvt.. doesn't seems like programming/a code.. | my reference : step 4 in both example.. 1 is "select 2 character and copy" and the 2nd is "select all & copy". Which is technically a different "Copy" step.

Comment: Sorry about my bad E. What I mean is that you have 3 manipulations and u have to use those manipulations to to have a string T like the example 2, we just need 7 manipulations instead using 11 "insert" manipulation to have a string T

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Approach**

For using the operation copy & paste, we need to keep track of every substring that can be made from the string we've built so far (string S). In c++ we can use map, unordered_map or use hash or trie, anything else.

We'll perform copy & paste only if we can paste a string whose length is greater than 1. Cause, if it's length is 1, then it'll take same
number of manupulation just to insert at the end.

Consider your first example. T=abcabab

Let's break it down.

> At first, result string S is empty. So we've only one option here.
> Insert character 'a' at the end of S. Increase manipulations count by 1.
>
> Now **S = "a"**, remaining target string **"bcabab"**, **Saved substring:**

> Insert character 'b' at the end of S. Increase manipulations count by 1.
>
> Now **S = "ab"**, remaining target string **"cabab"**, **Saved substring: "ab"**

> Our substring list is not empty now. So we'll try to make substring from our >remaining target string and check if that exists in our substring list.
>
> remaining target string **"cabab"**, **Saved substring: "ab"**
>
> So we'll first check if "ca" exists in our substring list. (not
> considering single character, cause we can just insert it) "ca"
> doesn't exist in the list, so we'll insert character 'c' at the end of S.
>
> Increase manipulations count by 1.
>
> Now **S = "abc"**, remaining target string **"abab"**, **Saved substring: "ab", "bc, "abc"**

> remaining target string **"abab"**, **Saved substring: "ab", "bc, "abc"**
>
> first check if "ab" exists in our substring list. It does. Now check if "aba" exists. It does not.
>
> So we'll save the string "ab" in a string variable (let's call it
> **lastCopiedString**), then insert "ab" at the end of S.
>
> Increase manipulations count by 2.
>
> Now **S = "abcab"**, remaining target string **"ab"**. **Saved substring: "ab", "bc", "ca", "abc", "bca", "cab", "abca", "bcab", "abcab". lastCopiedString = "ab"**

> remaining target string **"ab"**,  **Saved substring: "ab", "bc", "ca", "abc", "bca", "cab", "abca", "bcab", "abcab". lastCopiedString = "ab"**
>
> first check if "ab" exists in our substring list. It does. There's no
> letter left in target string. So check if the lastCopiedString is same as
> "ab". It's same in this case.
>
> Increase manipulations count by 1.
>
> Now **S = "abcabab"**, remaining target string "".
>
> Saved substring: "ab", "bc", "ca", "abc", "bca", "cab", "aba", "bab", "abca", "bcab", "caba", "abab", "abcab", "cabab", "bcabab", "abcaba", "abcabab" lastCopiedString = "ab"

> We've our result , which is 6.

Your question is not clear here. From comment section, i understood you need to output the number of min manipulations require to change S to T .
Also you haven't mentioned any constraints, max time complexity.
Please try editing the post, and mention as much detail as you can. So that anyone sees your post, understands it.

I tried to share a generalized idea from what I've understood.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot some details that the length of T is 100 and this problems is multi test have max about 100 test. 
The max complexity is ( O n^3 )

Comment: In that case mentioned approach will pass.

Comment: i don't think it's a true solution cause you can copy a sub string to clipboard and can use it to paste later, while you can use another manipulation to get closer to the target string. Maybe it's more sufficent, instead of finding in the substring or current clipboard and continue doing it with the target string like that. Those test is not difficult to see it.

Comment: From target string, you'll first see how far you can match with your current substring list. If your target string is "abcd", first check for "ab", then "abc", then "abcd". Then you'll continues with the largest matched one. If it's already copied, then just paste it. Otherwise copy and paste.

Comment: I think your solution wrong with example 2

Comment: You're right. Brute force will not work here. All possible combination needs to be checked here. Can you share the problem link? I'll try with a dp based solution.

Comment: It's my homework, I just have file from my teacher, srr.

Answer (score 0):

We can have an `O(n^2 * log n)` dynamic program state of `dp[i][sub]` where `i` is the current index and `sub` is which substring was used to create the suffix of the prefix ending at the `i`th index.

```
dp_0 = 1 // A constant

dp[i][sub] = min(
  // Insert one character
  1 + dp[i-1][best], // best is the min for dp[i-1]
  
  // Only pasting 
  1 + dp[j-1][sub]
    if exists sub T[j..i] in dp[j-1]
    
  // Copy and paste
  2 + dp[j-1][best]
    if we've seen T[j..i] before j;
    which we can check in log n time
    by storing an ordered list of
    indexes where each substring
    we've seen appears, hashed by
    the substring.
)

for j from i-1 down to 1
```

Python code:

```py
import bisect

# Assumes the string does
# not contain the substring,
# "best" :)
def f(T):
  seen = {}
  dp = [{"best": float('inf')} for _ in range(len(T) + 1)]
  dp[0]["best"] = 1

  for i in range(1, len(T)):
    sub = T[i]

    # Insert one character
    dp[i]["best"] = min(dp[i]["best"], 1 + dp[i-1]["best"])

    for j in range(i-1, 0, -1):
      sub = T[j] + sub

      if sub in seen:
        seen[sub].append(i)
      else:
        seen[sub] = [i]

      # Copy and paste
      end_of_sub_in_T_before_j = float('inf')

      insertion_pt = bisect.bisect_left(seen[sub], j)
      if insertion_pt - 1 >= 0:
        end_of_sub_in_T_before_j = seen[sub][insertion_pt - 1]

      if end_of_sub_in_T_before_j < j:
        dp[i][sub] = 2 + dp[j-1]["best"]

      # Paste only
      if sub in dp[j-1]:
        dp[i][sub] = min(dp[i][sub], 1 + dp[j-1][sub])

      # Best for dp[i]
      dp[i]["best"] = min(dp[i]["best"], dp[i][sub] if sub in dp[i] else float('inf'))
    
    seen[T[0] + sub] = [i]

  return dp[len(T)-1]["best"]

strs = [
  "abcabab",
  "aaaaaaaaaaa"
]

for T in strs:
  print(T)
  print(f(T))
  print("")
```